# Change attribute dynamically in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attributes, runtime

I'm new to WPF and XAML.
I have, for example this:

```
<TextBlock Name="txtTitle" Text="I want to change this" ></TextBlock>
```

in code to change the text attribute is easy:

```
txtTitle.Text="this change the text";
```

But I take some attributes from a configuration file and so I want to make a procedure that iterate all attributes from config and then change dinamically all the XAML attributes

I'm searching to something that make this:

```
txtTitle.Attribute("Text").value = "this change the text";
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those attributes are just *properties*, you can change those via **reflection** if you only have that information available dynamically. Once the XAML is parsed and the CLR object created this has nothing to do with XML.

It should be something like

```
txtTitle.GetType()
        .GetProperty(propertyName)
        .SetValue(txtTitle, propertyValue);
```

Comment: Oh Thank you, is esactly what I search for.

Comment: Oh Thank you, is esactly what I search for.